# laravel attach missing id SQL NOT NULL CONSTRAINT

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I try to attach 2 objects in a many to many relationship in Laravel.

So I have Users and Teams. When I try to `$user->teams()->attach($team->id, ['instrument_user_id' => $randomInstrument, 'is_leader' => $is_leader]);` I got the next error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: team_members.user_id (SQL: insert into "team_members" ("team_id", "instrument_user_id", "is_leader") values (73, 1, 0))
```

When I try to `$team->members()->attach($user->id, ['instrument_user_id' => $randomInstrument, 'is_leader' => $is_leader]);` I got the next error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: team_members.team_id (SQL: insert into "team_members" ("user_id", "instrument_user_id", "is_leader") values (1, 1, 0))
```

So where do I have to add the id of the item I want to attach, or what am I doing wrong?

**Usermodel:**

```
public function teams(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team', 'team_members', 'team_id')
                    ->as('details')
                    ->withPivot('instrument_user_id', 'is_leader')
                    ->using('App\TeamMember');
    }
```

**Team model:**

```
public function members()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\User', 'team_members', 'user_id')
                    ->as('details')
                    ->withPivot('instrument_user_id','is_leader')
                    ->using('App\TeamMember');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this relations:

**Team model:**

```
public function teams(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team', 'team_members', 'team_id', 'user_id')
                    ->as('details')
                    ->withPivot('instrument_user_id', 'is_leader')
                    ->using('App\TeamMember');
    }
```

**Team model:**

```
public function members()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\User', 'team_members', 'user_id', 'team_id')
                    ->as('details')
                    ->withPivot('instrument_user_id','is_leader')
                    ->using('App\TeamMember');
    }
```

Comment: Oh, that was easy! thanks! I was looking for it for 3 days, you saved my project!